# Custom single template for a specific category

Tags: theme-development, templates

What is the best way (performance & code structure) to create a custom template for a WordPress Post, which belong to a specific category? I realized that you can’t just create `single-catname.php`.

So far i tried two ways to change the template. But which one (or another one) is the best?

**EDIT:**

Any idea how to include all the sub/parent and so on categories to? I realized right now it only shows the main category...

**1.** Added to functions.php

```
function get_custom_cat_template($single_template) {
   global $post;
   if ( in_category( 'movies' )) {
      $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-movies.php';
   }
   return $single_template;
} 
add_filter( "single_template", "get_custom_cat_template" ) ;
```

**2.** Put the following Code in to single.php (instead of all other code) and create a `single-template.php` (with the code from the single.php) & a `custom single-movies.php`

```
<?php        
if(has_term('movies', 'category', $post)) {      
   get_template_part('single-movies', 'movies');
} else {
   // use default template file single-template.php
   get_template_part('single-template');
}
?>
```

Comment: My opinion, use what you are comfortable with. If there are any performance difference it will be minute/irrelevant. My preference, use the filter

Comment: Thx for the quick response. Any idea how to include all the sub/parent and so on categries to? I realized right now it only shows the main cat...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From my comment to the OP

> My opinion, use what you are comfortable with. If there are any performance difference it will be minute/irrelevant. My preference, use the filter

To come to your real concern/question, in my opinion, the best approach will be to use the parent category ID and work from there. It will be the least resource intensive to work from here. Reverse engineering can become quite an unnecessary waste of resources.

Make use of [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) to get the child categories from the given category. You can make use of either one of two parameters, either `parent` or `child_of`

> **parent** (integer)
>
> Display only categories that are direct descendants (i.e. children only) of the category identified by its ID. This does NOT work like the 'child_of' parameter. There is no default for this parameter. [In 2.8.4]
>
> **child_of** (integer)
>
> Display all categories that are descendants (i.e. children & grandchildren) of the category identified by its ID. There is no default for this parameter. If the parameter is used, the hide_empty parameter is set to false.

Once you have these, use [`wp_list_pluck`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) to get the catID, name or slug fields from the returned array of categories. This array will be used to check if a post belongs to one of these categories. You can either use [`has_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) or [`in_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

This is how you can extend your code to make sure that posts belonging to either the parent category or its descendants uses the given template

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $single_template ) {

    $parent     = '21'; //Change to your category ID
    $categories = get_categories( 'child_of=' . $parent );
    $cat_names  = wp_list_pluck( $categories, 'name' );

    if ( has_category( 'movies' ) || has_category( $cat_names ) ) {
        $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-movies.php';
    }
    return $single_template;
     
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

Comment: Any feedback on this? It would be appreciated (and good manners) if you can leave feedback to your **open** questions. It would not only benefit you, but the other users finding your questions via search engines. Simply abandoning your questions as you did might lead to other users ignoring your questions in future. Please help us (and **yourself**) to keep this site and your questions constructive. Thanks for understanding :-)

Comment: Works correct to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

step 1: Create or copy content-single.php and create a new file. eg: content-yourCategory.php
step 2: Open single.php and replace this `get_template_part('content','single');` by the following code

```
    if(is_category('yourCategory')){
        get_template_part('content','yourCategory');
    }else{
        get_template_part('content','single.php');
    }
```

The parameter can be Category ID, Category Title, Category Slug or Array of IDs, names, and slugs.

Comment: `in_category()` *

Answer (score 4):

This is a convenient way of doing that, found [here](https://halgatewood.com/wordpress-custom-single-templates-by-category) past this code into your `function.php`

```
// Custom single template by category
// https://halgatewood.com/wordpress-custom-single-templates-by-category

add_filter('single_template', 'check_for_category_single_template');
function check_for_category_single_template( $t )
{
  foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) 
  { 
    if ( file_exists(STYLESHEETPATH . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php") ) return STYLESHEETPATH . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php"; 
    if($cat->parent)
    {
      $cat = get_the_category_by_ID( $cat->parent );
      if ( file_exists(STYLESHEETPATH . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php") ) return STYLESHEETPATH . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php";
    }
  } 
  return $t;
}
```

for more info check out https://halgatewood.com/wordpress-custom-single-templates-by-category

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_custom_cat_template($single_template) {
   global $post;

      if ( in_category( 'category-name' )) {
         $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-template.php';
      }
   return $single_template;
}

add_filter( "single_template", "get_custom_cat_template" ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**OLD SOLUTIONS ARE NOT WORKING FOR THE NEW WORDPRESS TEMPLATES (BLOCK TEMPLATES)?**

For those who are coming here from google after 2022:

If you are working with **block templates**, the new template system for WP, that template files are not .php files but just .html files including blocks codes, you can use this answer:

Just create **single-post-[category slug]-article.html**. It works.

More precisely, this is the order for block template files, WP searchs for the single post:

1. single-post-[category slug]-article.html
2. single-post.html
3. single/html